# Partition is not mounted but locked (LiveUSB)

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, live-usb, ext4, ext3

I booted from a live usb to resize the partition, but it still locked, though it is not mounted, what am i doing wrong?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8AAR.jpg)

Comment: What do you want to do with the partition?

Comment: @sudodus resize, cut

Comment: You can't use gparted for this task. Use the special tools for LVM, according to the link in the answer by @VinylThePooh.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you're using LVM for the partition you want to resize, it's not necessary to boot on a live partition, LVM can do that while the system is up.

See the [documentation on the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) for more details

Comment: But I can't resize it anyway